# Display all comments and order them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to display all comments (total number) on 'all' page. So, not all comments for a specific Post, but all comments in the entire app. I've tried with Comment.all, but it says it can't find post without an ID...

> .../comments/all

routes

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
      member do
        put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
      end     
    end
  end
```

comments_controller

```
  def all
    ?
  end

  def index
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comments = @auto.comments.order("cached_votes_score DESC")
  end

  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
  end
 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a not nested route to comments:

routes

```
 resources :posts do
    resources :comments do
      member do
        put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
        put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
      end     
    end
  end

  get "comments#all"
```

comments_controller

```
def all
  @comments=Comment.all
end
```

Comment: This is good - I just had to use: match 'comments/all' => "comments#all", via: [:get]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `PostsController` because what you want is not actually directly relevant to a post.

Try adding a `collection` route for `comment`

```
resources :comments do
  member do
    ..
  end

  collection do
    get :all # actually that is index
  end
end
```

or simpler

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :comments, only: :index
```

and then a

```
#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
def index
  Comment.all
end
```

on your `CommentsController` will do.